# JTextField.getInputContext() returns null value

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextfield

In my Swing application, I use `JTextField` component to get Farsi text values.

I want to set locale for this component by using the following code:

```
txt_fname.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("fa", "IR"));
```

But `txt_fname.getInputContext()` returns `null` and the code throws a `NullPointerException`.

How can I solve this problem?

**Edited**

the code is called in InternalJFrame constructor:

```
public DriversList() {
    initComponents();
    txt_fname.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("fa", "IR"));        
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: From the Java docs: "the input context used by this component; null if no context can be determined" So in your case, no context could be determined. Maybe you can create a new Context-Object and someway set it for the JTextField..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This MCVE suggests the code you have not shown, is attempting to get the input context before the text field is first displayed.

### Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class InputContextTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);
                System.out.println(tf.getInputContext());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tf);
                System.out.println(tf.getInputContext());
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

### Output

```
null
sun.awt.im.InputMethodContext@1fa5e5e
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I use the code in JFrame constructor! Can it be the cause?

Comment: Thanks, the problem solved by using a Runnable object to call the code changing locale value and invoke it later.